# Cannot access SMB share (Freenas) from one computer (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba, windows-server-2003, freenas

I cannot access an SMB share (shared on Freenas) from one computer (running Windows Server 2003). The same share is accessible by other computers. I/ve tried accessing it directly, mounting as a letter drive, or using commands:

```
net use z: \\nas\SHARENAME /user:nas\USER PASSWD
```

(with variations using IP instead of DNS name, `/user:IP\USER`, `/user:USER`).

I get error 1326 (wrong user or password).

I've tried accessing different user, I deleted and recreated the user, permissions and share on Freenas etc. The share works fine on other computers, but is stuck on this old Windows Server machine.

The dates on both systems are the same. I can ping the freenas server by dns name or IP and I can list the shares. Local security policy is set to classic (secpol.msc).

What else can I check?

Comment: This may be related to the SMB version your FreeNAS is exposing vs what your Server2003 is using as the client...

Comment: @Kinnectus - I've just checked samba settings on Freenas. There's a "server minimum protocol", which is empty, and "server maximum protocol " which is set to SMB3. I've changed it to CORE and SMB3_11 (min and max available) but it didn't help.

Comment: Ah, according to http://olddoc.freenas.org/index.php/CIFS leaving the "server minimum protocol" to blank (or the default value) configures for automatic protocol negotiation. I'd put it back to what it was. Sorry!

Comment: You may need to amend the local security policy: https://www.fir3net.com/Microsoft/General/windows-system-error-1326-has-occurred.html

Comment: @Kinnectus - I've tried that, forgot to mention. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @namq SMB minimum needs to be set to SMB2, as SMBv1 is exploitable on any device leaving it enabled, opening the device to numerous forms of ransomware due to SMBv1.  Have you reviewed **(1)** The [FreeNAS forum](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/), and **(2)** The [FreeNAS manual](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2-U7-legacy/freenas.html)?  _(A user should be checking both over Stack Exchange.)_

Answer (score 0):

Use a network sniffer to check if your smb client adds the domain name to the username before trying to authenticate.

Comment: The OP has already tried to connect by providing the domain name... `net use z: \\nas\SHARENAME /user:nas\USER PASSWD`

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, had to connect temporarily from an old Windows 2003 server to FreeNAS server.

In FreeNAS admin:
Services / SMB / Configure

Make sure you check **NTLMv1 Auth** (it's off by default, due to security vulnerabilities).

[image]

Once you don't need the legacy client anymore, I suggest to turn-it off again.